# List with structure <String, List<String>>

Tags: java, collections

I need to create a data structure that can hold data in the following layout:

```
{ "1", { "1", "2", "3", ... } }
```

In other words, a list with the structure `<String, List<String>>`. This data structure then needs to be put in a Hashmap, like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapper = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: Create a class that contains the String and the List<String> as properties. You can also make it generic if you want - something like `class SomeObject<T, List<T>>` - then you can use a `List<SomeObject<String, List<String>>`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>> mapper = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
Map<String, List<String>> mapper = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
mapper.put("1",list);
```

And if you want to hold multiple structure then use following also

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,List<String>>>();
mapList.add(mapper);
```